# I need help making a toString method that must pass certain tests, Java

Tags: java, tostring, singly-linked-list

I need help making this toString method pass the tests at the bottom. I am currently getting the error (expected:<0:20, 1:[1]0> but was <0:20, 1:[2]0>). addFirst is working 100%, but I'm not sure what is wrong here.

```
public class LList
{
  public Node head;
  private int i;
  private int size;

public void addFirst(int value)
{
    Node n = new Node();
    n.value = value;
    n.next = head;
    head = n;
}

public void removeFirst()
{
    if (head != null)
    {
        // commone case: there is at least one node
        head = head.next;
    }
    else
    {
        // no nodes
        throw new Banana();
    }
}

public int size()
{
    Node current = head;
    int count = 0;
    while(current != null)
    {
        count++;                    // keep count of nodes
        current = current.next;     // move to next node
    }
    return count;
}

public int get(int index)
{
    int count = 0;
    Node current = head;
    if (index < 0 || index >= size())
    {
        throw new Banana();
    }
    while(count != index)
    {
        count++;
        current = current.next;
    }
    return current.value;
}

   public String toString()
     {
    String s = "";
    Node current = head;
    //current = head;

    if (size() == 0)
    {
    return s;
    }
    else
    {
    s = s + "" + i + ":" + current.value;
    for (int i = 1; i < size(); i++)
    {
        s = s + ", " + i + ":" + current.value;
    }
    return s;
    }
}


public class Node
{
    public int value;
    public Node next;
}

@Test
public void testToString()
{
    LList a = new LList();
    assertEquals("", a.toString());
    a.addFirst(10);
    assertEquals("0:10", a.toString());
    a.addFirst(20);
    assertEquals("0:20, 1:10", a.toString());
    a.addFirst(30);
    assertEquals("0:30, 1:20, 2:10", a.toString());
}
```

Comment: my guess is that you are talking about Java, but you probably should tag this with an actual programming language

Comment: @johnbakers that slipped my mind, just edited.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need toString to pass certain tests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32939772/need-tostring-to-pass-certain-tests)

Comment: Are you re-taking the class from last semester? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32939772/need-tostring-to-pass-certain-tests

Comment: You might benefit from using a good debugging tool or technique. With a debugging tool, you can step through your code line by line and see what it's doing. Or, you can use certain techniques, such as adding print statements or alerts, to trace your program's execution without a debugger. More helpful info here: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)  ... In this case, you might try putting a println in your loop and printing out `current`.

Comment: @shoover Same principle but never got an answer for it. But back at it again. Different class for it though. It's a similar assignment for review.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Displaying a linked list in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35835133/displaying-a-linked-list-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate (walk over) all Nodes.

Use `while` loop for that, e.g.:

```
public String toString() {
    String s = "";
    Node current = head;
    // current = head;

    if (size() != 0) {
        int i = 0;
        s = s + "" + i + ":" + current.value;
        while(current.next != null) {
            i++;
            current = current.next;
            s = s + ", " + i + ":" + current.value;
        } 
    }
    return s;
}
```